# Is this a use case for pypy?

Tags: python, pypy

I am working on an application with a few nested loops of non vectorizable code. There's a group of around 50 functions that get called hundreds or thousands of times. These functions receive dictionaries and pass dictionaries back. Each function is very short, each with simple numerical code,  so just compiling the functions will not do much good. I think that I need to compile both the loop with the functions. Cython could work but I am worried about the amount of work in maintaining type declarations on so many functions plus not getting big improvements due to all those dictionaries being passed around.
I was wondering if this is a good use case for PyPy. There's no numpy or c extensions involved. Just simple functions reading off inputs from a dictionary and updating those dictionaries.

I've read the documentation for PyPy where it says that short-running processes will not be improved by PyPy. I am wondering if this short-running functions will prevent the JIT compiler from improving the runtime.

What do you think? Any experience with pypy on something similar is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) :)

Comment: Maybe you could also find a way to use `namedtuple`s instead of the dictionaries

Comment: @MikhailBurshteyn to what end?

Comment: `namedtuple`s should be faster in construction and element access, so this would likely improve performance

Comment: Short-running *functions* are no problem for PyPy. The docs are talking about if your *entire program* finishes quickly with little time for JIT warmup.

Comment: @roganjosh thanks, I didn't, but they don't support dictionaries in nopython mode. The issue has been open for a long time with no signs of a concrete implementation date. Even if I changed to namedtuples, I need closures which numba does not support.

Comment: @MikhailBurshteyn thanks for the suggestion. Actually namedtuples would be an option for us, probably a better one than dictionaries. I didn't know they would be faster than dicts.

Answer (score 1):

The term short-running refers to the quantity of code executed, not the wall-clock time. The JIT traces code execution and only kicks in when it sees a section of code repeat ~1000 times.

Comment: thanks for the info @mattip, what happens if a section does not run 1000 times? would performance be comparable to CPython? Or are there other additional advantages in PyPy, e.g. lower function call overhead, or disadvantages, e.g. JIT startup time?

Comment: The best before-you-start information is available on the [PyPy website](http://www.pypy.org/performance.html) and in its [documentation](http://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html). You should try it out. Write your benchmark which is meaningful to you, then run it under CPython and PyPy and compare. The best test is your use case.